# Get user in a Rest Controller class instead of each controller method

Tags: java, spring

I have a `@RestController` with bunch of Rest endpoints as methods.

```
@RequestMapping(path="",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void create(Principal principal) {
    String userName = principal.getName();
    User user = UsersRepository.loadUser(userName);
    //....
}

@RequestMapping(path="/{groupId}",method=RequestMethod.DELETE)
public void deleteGroup(@PathVariable String groupId, Principal principal) {
    String userName = principal.getName();
    User user = UsersRepository.loadUser(userName);
    //....
}
```

In each method I have to repeat this code:

```
    String userName = principal.getName();
    User user = UsersRepository.loadUser(userName);
```

Is there a way not to repeat this in each method and get it in the class, and consume it in each method ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Very basic but why not simply extract it in a private method :

```
public User getUser(Principal principal){
  String userName = principal.getName();
  User user = UsersRepository.loadUser(userName);
  //....
  return user;
}
```

You could write so :

```
@RequestMapping(path="",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public void create(Principal principal) {
    User user = getUser(principal);
    //....
}
```

2) More advanced : you could use a Spring interceptor that reads in the request, loads the user and wires it in a bean with a request scope.

Comment: @Vinod Kumar The controller constructor option is not suitable as the Rest controller is stateless and may receive requests from multiple users.

Comment: didn't think of stateless. Thanks.

Comment: @Vinod Kumar  You are welcome :) Rest and web controllers are indeed designed to be stateless.